# how to upload a bigger file using Blobdata

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Good day Everyone,

I am having a problem in uploading a file that is greater than 2mb. In here I use a blobdata (bytBLOBData). Here's the code for reference.

try
            {
                OpenFileDialog myOPD = new OpenFileDialog();
                myOPD.Filter = "Image files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

```
            if (myOPD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pat = myOPD.FileName;
                string sPath = myOPD.FileName;

                var fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
                //Open FileStream to read file 
                FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                //Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array. 
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
                numBytes = fInfo.Length;
                bytBLOBData = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(numBytes));
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytBLOBData);

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(myOPD.FileName);
                String strName = fi.Name;
                txtManual.Text = strName;
                txtreferencename.Focus();
                br.Close();
                fStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            validation.ErrorMessage("load");
        }
    }
```

I've research about this problem before, some forums told me that I should use a CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, but I don't get it right. Any help is highly appreciated :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do ? I don't understand the purpose of your code, and there is no mention to the file upload. If you simply want to upload a file, use [`WebClient.UploadFile` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144229.aspx).

Comment: Actually, the problem is when I start debugging it, the file that I am uploading is corrupted (if i am uploading a file that is greater than 2mb but if not it works fine). What i am trying to is I am uploading a .pdf file, these .pdf files are manuals that consist of texts and images. These code was just a chunk of a bigger project, I am just working on a module that uploads a .pdf file. and stored it in the database. but when the file is bigger the file that I was uploaded was corrupted. Maybe you have some knowledge in it or past experiences about this matter, mind if you share. :) Thank you

Comment: you should put the code of the upload part of the code... the problem may reside in this part